# Custom BST file not being used

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, miktex, texniccenter

I am preparing a paper for a journal, which provided a custom LaTeX class file and a custom BST Bibtex style file for me to use.

As this is just a one-time use, I simply put both the class file and the BST file in the same folder with my tex file.

I then build my file to pdf, using Texnic Center with Miktex. The end of my document reads

```
\bibliographystyle{journalstyle}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

where journalstyle.bst is the journal-provided style file and mybib.bib is the name of my .bib file.

The journal's class file works fine, but the **Bibtex refuses to use the custom BST file when running,** making my references appear the same way before (and actually all wrong because of their interaction with the new class file).

When I run Bibtex on its own on this document, Bibtex tells me it is using some other style file on my computer, amsrn.bst, even though I am explicitly telling it to use journalstyle.bst.

Can anyone help?

Comment: does your paper either explicitly, or via the journal class file, `\usepackage{amsrefs}`?

Comment: Aha! Thank you Barbara, removing that fixed the problem. I feel a bit silly that the solution was so simple, but I'd been staring at this for some time. If you write your comment as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: by the way, welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the file `amsrn.bst` is loaded by `\usepackage{amsrefs}`, so if that command
appears in either your file or the class file, it will override the other
`\bibliographystyle` request.